# Are the Argument From Perspectival Variation and the Argument From Perceptual Relativity one and the same?

Tags: empiricism, realism, perception, berkeley, anti-realism

The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy explains [Perspectival Variation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sense-data/#ArgPerVar) as follows:

> Perspectival variation is the kind of variation in one's sensory
>   experiences that normally attends changes in one's spatial or other
>   physical relationship to the physical objects one is observing. ...
>   suppose you are viewing a table. If you move closer to or farther from
>   the table, your sensory experience changes. If you move laterally
>   relative to the table, your sensory experience will change in another
>   way

The Argument From Perspectival Variation is based on the above idea of perspectival variation. The argument is that reality might not be perceived directly by the human observer.

I've had trouble finding a proper source on the other argument, the Argument From Perceptual Relativity, which is part of the reason why I'm left confused about whether the second argument is just another name for the Argument From Perspectival Variation, as the explanation in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAhyLT438QM) seems to suggest, or whether it differs in the way it's seems to be explained in [a blog](https://frankdevita.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/idealism-and-perceptual-relativity-do-you-see-what-i-see/):

> each perceiver apprehends a different object entirely, rather than a
>   different affection of the same object as a consequence of having
>   different points of view.

My question is whether the Argument From Perspectival Variation and the Argument From Perceptual Relativity both revolve around perceiving the same object from different angles, or whether only the former revolves around this whereas the latter revolves around different people perceiving different objects even when they observe the same object from the same angle.

Comment: For what it's worth, I left a comment on Frank Devita's blog asking him if he has an answer to your question.